# Python if statement: False vs. 0.0

Tags: python, if-statement

Is it possible to:

```
for k,v in kwargs.items()
    if v == None or v == '' or v == 1.0 or v == False:
       del kwargs[k]
```

without deleting the key if v == 0.0? (False seems to equal 0.0), and without deleting the keys who equal True.

Comment: FYI this works in Python 2.x, but in Python 3, `.items()` returns a lazily-iterated object instead of a list of item tuples. Deleting items while iterating over the dictionary will lead to a `RuntimeError` then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Or you can put it like this :

```
if v in (None, '', 1.0) or v is False:
```

Comment: Nope. `0.0 in (None,'',1.0,False)` -> True because the linear search `in` of sequences uses `==` (which is usually the wanted behaviour, but not here).

Comment: @delnan: yes , i just change it , the problem is with False , because 0.0 == False , so he should just put "is False"

Comment: Fails for v=True, because 1.0 == True.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen: yes you are right but i think Izz has already correct it :)

Answer (score 11):

You should use `v is False` instead of `v == False`. The same applies for your comparison to `None`. See [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with 'is' or 'is not', never the equality operators.

Comment: You absolutely *should* (applies to all singletons, e.g. `True` and `None`).

Comment: @delnan: Yes, you are right. I changed the wording and added some more detail.

Comment: ...and if you do, you can drop the `or v ==''` part.

Comment: But this doesn't apply to True / False.  See the last point in http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ : *Good*: `if greeting` ; *Bad*: `if greeting == True` ; *Worst*: `if greeting is True`

Comment: @James Blackburn: That's regarding testing a boolean value, but that's not going to work here. Read the question: he doesn't want to test if the value is truthy, he specifically wants to test the type too. Note at the top of the style guide: "But **most importantly**: know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the style guide just doesn't apply." Of course you could argue that the OP shouldn't be trying doing this in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

Slow down guys with your advice, from PEP 8:

> Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==
>
> ```
>    Yes:   if greeting:
>
>    No:    if greeting == True:
>
>    Worse: if greeting is True:
> ```

Also comparing float value you **should not use ==** but

**abs(x-other) < verysmall**

Comment: `if not x` beats `if x == False`, for sure. But here, the question is how to check if something really is the boolean value `False`, not something "falsy".

Answer (score 1):

Also you could use

```
if not v:
    # do something
```

This may not be quite as precise as `if v is False` as it also runs for if `v` is `0`, `None`, `empty set` etc.

I had trouble with this problem and the above solution worked for me.

Comment: Can you include a more explained answer with more code?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. Using the suggestions, the problem was solved:

```
kwargs = {'None': None, 'empty': '', 'False': False, 'float': 1.0, 'True': True}       
for k,v in kwargs.items():
    if v in (None, '', 1.0) and v is not True:
        del kwargs[k]
    if v is False:
        del kwargs[k]

kwargs
{'True': True}
```

-->

```
kwargs = {'None': None, 'empty': '', 'False': False, 'float': 0.0, 'True': True}       
for k,v in kwargs.items():
     if v in (None, '', 1.0) and v is not True:
         del kwargs[k]
     if v is False:
         del kwargs[k]

kwargs
{'True': True, 'float': 0.0}
```